# it is possible to rewrite this promise as a async function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, promise

I wrote this promise, where I fetch and .json with objects that contains personal datas

```
const cpf_person = new Map()

fetch('pessoas.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response =>{
     for (let object of response) {
        const {cpf} = object
        console.log(cpf)
        cpf_person
        
 .set(cpf, object)
     } return cpf_person
 
})
.then(map => console.log(map, map.size, map.get('103.439.122-44')))
```

on the second `.then` use a for loop to create a new Map from those objects, then return to the third one to manipulate it.
I've be trying to repeat this process using async function, but I'm getting problems on the second `.then` where I use the for loop, I achieved this so far:

```
const cpf_person2 = new Map()

async function tal(){
    const fet =     await fetch('pessoas.json')
    const json =    await fet.json()
    const loop =    await json => { (json => { //I'm not passing through this stage
        for (let object of response) {
            const {cpf} = object
            console.log(cpf)
            cpf_person.set(cpf, object)
        }
    })
}
}
```

I know I can just write the for loop on the function without using it as a promise, but is possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*using it as a promise*". Why would you even want to do that, there's nothing asynchronous about this loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are stuck in a ".then" -mindset.

Think of your function (tal) as executing line by line.
When there is an `await`, the next line won't execute until the await line finished its job.

To fix, move the loop out of the function and delete the function line entirely and change the loop to `for (let object of json) { ...`.

```js
async function tal(){
    const fet = await fetch('pessoas.json')
    const json = await fet.json()
    for (let object of json) {
        const {cpf} = object
        console.log(cpf)
        cpf_person.set(cpf, object)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `return` statement